# Does variable declaration hoist to the top of if scope block?

Tags: javascript

When hoisting is occurring to the variable which declaring with keyword var inside an if block scope, does the ( var x;) hoisting to the top of current if block? or to the top of the global scope in this case?
Suppose we wrote the following piece of code directly in the global scope

```
if (true) {
   some code;
   var x = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `var` (or omitting the definition key at all e.g just `x = 1`) as per your example, it would be hoisted to the closest scope which in your example would be the global scope (`window`).

If it would be wrapped in a function, then the function would be the closest scope.

```js
function a() {
    if(true){
       var x=1;
    }
    console.log(x) // 1
    console.log(window.x) // undefined
}
a()
console.log(x) // Throws error (x is not defined)
```

If you want the variable to be completely block scope, then you would need to use `let` or `const`.

```js
if(true){
    const x=1;
}
console.log(x) // Throws error (x is not defined)
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that yes, the declaration is hoisted but not to the top of the block. It is hoisted to the global level. *But where it is assigned does not change*.

This is tricky to test because an undeclared variable and a declared variable will both produce a `typeof somevar` of `undefined`.

```js
var myVar;

console.log('typeof myVar');
console.log(typeof myVar);


console.log('typeof notDeclared');
console.log(typeof notDeclared);
```

However, if you try to use an defined variable it will throw an error, so we can use that to find out what has been declared and what has not.

```js
var myVar;

try {
  myVar;
  console.log('myVar was declared');
} catch(error) {
  console.log(error);
}

try {
  notDeclared;
  console.log('notDeclared was declared');
} catch(error) {
  // Error is unfortunately captured by the sandbox,
  // so we just get an empty object. :-(
  console.log(error);
}
```

Putting it all together, we can test your code to see what happens.

```js
// Does myVar exist in global scope?
try {
  myVar;
  console.log('myVar exists in global scope.');
} catch (error) {
  console.log('myVar does NOT exist in global scope.');
}

if (true) {

  console.log('myVar value before assignment.', myVar);

  var myVar = 1;

  console.log('myVar value after assignment.', myVar);

}
```

Comment: That's not quite how it works... try assigning a value to the "undeclared" entity myvar before your if statement and you shouldn't see an error.

Comment: @JasonB thanks, my first answer wasn't quite right. I think the edited version gets it right.

Comment: Nice! Good research

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely.

```js
// hoisted
if( true){
   x = 1;
   console.log( x, typeof x );
   var x;
}

// doesn't do what you thought it would, the assignment doesn't move, just the declaration.
if( true){
   console.log( y, typeof y );
   var y = 1;
}
```

Comment: wonderful example, but to be more specific,does the (var x) in the upper example hoist to the top of ( if block ) scope or to the top of global scope?

Comment: To the top of scope, that is top of function or script, not block, switch, nor if.

Comment: Good question. Looks like @Todd Chaffee has it worked out here in his answer.